# Should I shrink this SQL Server data file?

Tags: sql-server, shrink

I have read many [articles](http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/why-you-should-not-shrink-your-data-files/) describing how shrinking data files causes terrible things to happen floods, famine, fragmentation, and general mayhem.

Here is the cliff notes of my situation:

1. SSAS company with a central logging database for all client errors.
2. Recent code roll created a new bug exponentially increasing the size of the database.
3. Bug is fixed and the useless records have been removed, approximately 70 million.
4. DB used space is now down to a normal level leaving 200+ gig of white space.

I am unable to find any posts or articles describing what I will gain from reclaiming this space.

Other than backup times increasing, are there ANY negative effects from a significant amount of unused space in a data file?

Please note the following in case it may help give a more informed answer:

1. The drive is not in danger of filling up
2. Space is not needed else where on the SAN
3. Backup times have double in duration (both full and differential)
4. Our DR SAN replication has slowed slightly.

Comment: How big was the database before this "bug" was introduced?  If it was 20GB, and then blew up to 200GB, I'd say you may benefit from a one-time shrink.

Comment: This is potentially a duplicate of [I Need to Shrink My Database - I just freed a lot of space](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/53857/i-need-to-shrink-my-database-i-just-freed-a-lot-of-space)

Comment: I am not sure if backups are faster. The only real benefit to my understanding is that you have free space :D on the HDD.

Comment: I agree with @MaxVernon and upvoted his answer. I just want to add that it is not _just_ backup time that has increased, but also the _restore_ time. Going by your 4 points: 1 and 2) never a good reason to wantonly waste large chunks of space. You might not need the space now, but the company didn't pay extra for enterprise-level storage because they thought they would never grow enough to need it; 3 and 4) are enough to make the question (in terms of the title, at least) an obvious yes :-)

Comment: @RayofCommand - backups would not likely be faster; especially if backup compression is enabled.  However, restoring a needlessly big data file will be far slower assuming "Instant File Initialization" is *not* enabled for the instance.  Restoring a needlessly large log file will *always* be slower than restoring the "right-sized" log, regardless.

Comment: On a typical "whoops" code release cycle it would top out at 350 gig. I was comfortable just leaving it alone at that size.

Comment: @RayofCommand That was part of my reason for posting here. I was unable to find any documentation on how white space effects backup operations. I use Olla Hallgren's backup solution logging the results, which was what allowed me to see the significant increase in backup completion times. That has stayed true after the record removal.

Answer (score 4):

Presuming you are sure the database is not going to need the 200+ GB of extra space it is currently consuming, I would recommend performing a shrink without reorganizing pages, using `TRUNCATEONLY`:

```
DBCC SHRINKFILE (N'<file name>' , 0, TRUNCATEONLY);
```

`TRUNCATEONLY` simply truncates the last part of the file without moving rows inside the data file.  This is important since it will prevent logical fragmentation of tables inside the data file.  If you perform the shrink without specifying `TRUNCATEONLY` SQL Server will move pages around inside the file to get the smallest possible file size, thereby creating anywhere from "some" to "a lot" of fragmentation, which may adversely affect performance. Read more about this at the [Books Online](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189493.aspx) page for `DBCC SHRINKFILE`.  Thanks to [@Zane](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/45427) for the suggestion to include these details in my answer.

Once you have performed the shrink, you may want to ensure the file growth parameters are set correctly.  For instance, ensure the file growth is not percentage based; use a number of MBs that makes sense for your expected growth rate.

Comment: I fully endorse this course of action.

Answer (score 1):

Caveat: how big is the data load? There is quite a difference between 20G of data with 200G of empty space (in which case I would suggest a shrink) and 2000G of data with 200G of empty space!

> The drive is not in danger of filling up
>   Space is not needed else where on the SAN

In that case I would err on the side of leaving it as it is, especially if normal growth will consume that extra space in a reasonable amount of time. If a fair chunk of the unused space is at the end of the data file(s) then a truncate might be worth doing: this just frees the end of the file and doesn't move anything.

> Backup times have double in duration (both full and differential)

As the backup process is bright enough not to bother reading and writing pages that are currently unused, that suggests that your data has a lot a part used pages rather than a lot of completely empty ones. Your backup file sizes have presumably grown by a similar order too. Running an index reorganise might be a better way of dealing with this than a DB shrink. After the reorganise you are likely to find you have more free space in the data files and some of the part used pages will be merged.

Having a lot of part used pages is more than a disk space use issue: it makes your use of RAM less efficient too because data is held in memory in page structure rather than being broken down differently. If all your pages were at most 50% used then you a potentially using twice as much memory as you otherwise could (or, if RAM is a limitation in your environment, you could be hitting disk a lot more often because you can only hold half as much in memory). This means running a reorganise over your indexes could affect application performance significantly so is probably a pretty good idea in that case.

You can get an indication of how efficiently your memory is being used by running:

```
SELECT
    (CASE WHEN ([database_id] = 32767)
        THEN N'Resource Database'
        ELSE DB_NAME ([database_id]) END) AS [DatabaseName],
    COUNT (*) * 8 / 1024 AS [MBUsed],
    SUM (CAST ([free_space_in_bytes] AS BIGINT)) / (1024 * 1024) AS [MBEmpty]
FROM sys.dm_os_buffer_descriptors
GROUP BY [database_id]
HAVING COUNT(*)>1024;
```

<sup>(taken from http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/performance-issues-from-wasted-buffer-pool-memory/ which is worth a read for more detail on what I've just said)</sup>

Just to be clear: this is a case for index reorganisation, not a case for a database shrink.

> Our DR SAN replication has slowed slightly.

Again this is likely due to having many part used pages: updates will be more scattered than if your data were more compact so more disk blocks are getting altered in the normal application load.

Remember that after a large operation like a shrink (or a significant set of index reorganisations/rebuilds) your next SAN replica will be considerably larger than normal because a lot of blocks on disk will have changed. The same for the next differential backup too.

> Other than backup times increasing, are there ANY negative effects from a significant amount of unused space in a data file?

If the space is mainly in the form of completely unused pages, then no (and the backup times shouldn't be increased, but restore times may be). If the space is mainly spread throughout part used pages then yes, as discussed above.

Comment: Good points, David.  It is important to understand what you are doing, and why you are doing it, prior to actually doing it.