# How to restore a database, ignoring the free space within each file?

Tags: sql-server, backup, restore, sql-server-2014

Using the following script I get all the disk space used by each file in my database:

```
;with radhe as (
SELECT 

DatabaseName = 'my Database', --DB_NAME(), 

a.FILEID, 

[FILE_SIZE_GB] = CONVERT(DECIMAL(12, 2), ROUND(a.size / 128.000/1024.000, 2)), 

[SPACE_USED_GB] = CONVERT(DECIMAL(12, 2), ROUND(fileproperty(a.NAME, 'SpaceUsed') / 128.000/1024.000, 2)), 

[FREE_SPACE_GB] = CONVERT(DECIMAL(12, 2), ROUND((a.size - fileproperty(a.NAME, 'SpaceUsed')) / 128.000/1024.000, 2)), 

a.NAME, a.FILENAME 

FROM dbo.sysfiles a)

select * from radhe
```

this results:

[image]

As you can see on the above picture, the amount of free space inside MyDatabase is high.

I need a copy of this database so that I can test some partitions operations.

Is there a way I can restore this database ignoring the free space in each file?

Basically I will use my "new database" to develop and test something, I would prefer to keep it small.

How could I achieve that?

Comment: RESTORE will restore the file sizes as they exist on the source server. If you want to restore a copy that is smaller, you'll need to shrink the source before you take a backup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way I can restore this database ignoring the free space in each file?

No you cannot. You can restore the database and then do a [shrink of database file](http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/category/shrink/).

I assume that you are aware of all the caution that the smart people have given.

- [I Need to Shrink My Database - I just freed a lot of space](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/53858/8783)
- [Why Does the Transaction Log Keep Growing or Run Out of Space?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/29829/why-does-the-transaction-log-keep-growing-or-run-out-of-space) - since you have a large `ldf` file.

> Basically I will use my "new database" to develop and test something, I would prefer to keep it small.

Why dont you use a [data generator](https://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-data-generator/) or [from here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/614382/1387418) or just get a sample of data from your PROD for testing ?